# a problem in unity convert from 'string' to 'System.Action<GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus>'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Assets\Managers\AdmobManager\Admob.cs(91,30): error CS1503: Argument
> 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
> 'System.Action<GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus>'

that part is problem : `MobileAds.Initialize(appId);`

Comment: Put code where is the problem. We cannot help you if we don't see your code.

Comment: From the error log: You give `String` as an argument to the function `MobileAds.Initialize()`. Instead of String you have to give `System.Action<GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus>`.
[link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/initialization/package-summary)

Answer (score 0):

The overload

```
MobileAds.Initialize(string appId)
```

is **deprecated** since [version 6.0.0](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v6.0.0)

> Removed `MobileAds.Initialize(string appId)`.

So the only one left now is

```
MobileAds.Initialize(Action<GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus> initCompleteAction)
```

which rather wants a method that takes a `GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus` as parameter like e.g.

```
MobileAds.Initialize(HandleInitComplete);

...

private void HandleInitComplete(GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus status)
{
    // ... do something after initialization completed
}
```

The app ID is rather configured [in the settings](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start#set_your_admob_app_id)!